# How to extend class for which you don't have source code?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, shared-libraries

I have a problem and I don't know how to begin solving this.
I'm doing this in C++.

Let's say that we have some executable program (UNIX platform) and we can run this program by typing my_program . Parameters are here 4 classes. Each of this classes must extend class, that is written in target program (in my_program).

So, let's say than in my_program we have class A, B, C and D. User knows that he must extend this classes, so he creates four child classes.

```
class A1 : public A { ... }
class B1 : public B { ... }
class C1 : public C { ... }
class D1 : public D { ... }
```

Is this possible? classes A, B, C and D are in my_program, so can he extend them in some way?

Comment: Don't inherit from their classes, make a whole new one that contains an instance of their class. Composition over inheritance and all that.

Comment: You mean like this?
`class A1
{
    A variable;
}`
and then in program I just call A.methodName?
Actuly is prety neat solution :D and simple :)

Comment: You can probably load the executable as a shared object but that is not a good idea. Just create a shared object and accompanying header file and let both my_program and the users program load the same shared object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ does not support this type of inheritance. Other languages, like C# allow this.

Although you can write this sort of derived class, when:

- Methods (especially ctor/dector) of your base class are exported from DLL or EXE;
- You have header with definition of the base class;
- You use the same compiler and same version of the compiler that the DLL is using.

In this case you can write application that contains your derived class. This will be a separate binary. It will load that DLL/EXE into its address space and call methods of the base class when needed. This is possible because they should be exported as this is required in the first bullet.

Comment: 1) I presume that you mean that I create static library and then link that library with that source code?
2) If I have this in target (my_program)
`class A 
{
    void method1() { implementation }
    void method2() { implementation }
}`

then, if I give user a header file like this
`class A
{
    void method1();
    void method2();
}`
then he can extend class A, but if he calls A.method1, will this call method from my target (my_program?)

Comment: No, my answer is all about linked binary. Case with static library is different. You need this library and headers. Nothing else.

Comment: Ok let me see if I got this right. I must export my class (and all of it's methods) to lib file (.so) and create header file with my class (and methods definitions) and give it to user so he can inherit this class A?

Comment: I do not know Unix based systems very well. I know it has mechanism, similar to Windows DLLs, but do not know details. You cannot export C++ class from binary file into a lib file in any system. If you link lib file into a binary, you cannot get .lib file back any more.

Comment: So, if I provide header with definition of the base class to user, then he can inherit from that class, he can call methods and so on. But, how will program knew that this class and methods are implemented in binary? Do I need to compile that user wrote in some specific way?